# Getting no query results in email

Tags: mysql, powershell

This is my powershell script below. I am trying to export the query's results into email body. However, the email contains nothing except the table headers. Could anyone help out what could be wrong / incomplete?

```psh
# Create a DataTable
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable "bugs"
$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn bug_id,([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn bug_status,([string])
$col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn resolution,([string])
$col4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn short_desc,([string])
$col5 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn deadline,([string])
$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)
$table.columns.add($col3)
$table.columns.add($col4)
$table.columns.add($col5)

# This code defines the search string in the database table
```

`$SQLQuery = "SELECT bug_id, 
       bug_status, 
       resolution, 
       short_desc, 
       deadline 
FROM   bugs 
WHERE  ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' ) 
         AND deadline BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
       ) 
        OR ( bug_status IN ( 'RESOLVED', 'VERIFIED', 'INTEST' ) 
             AND deadline BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND 
                                  CURDATE() )

       ORDER BY deadline ASC 
"`

```
# This code connects to the SQL server and retrieves the data
$MySQLAdminUserName = 'user_name'
$MySQLAdminPassword = 'password'
$MySQLDatabase = 'mantis'
$MySQLHost = '<HOSTNAME>'
$ConnectionString = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";port=3306;uid=" + $MySQLAdminUserName + ";pwd=" + $MySQLAdminPassword + ";database="+$MySQLDatabase

[void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\Devolutions\Remote Desktop Manager Free\MySQL.Data.dll")
$Connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$Connection.Open()

$Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($SQLQuery, $Connection)
$DataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command)
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$RecordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
$DataSet.Tables[0]  

# Create an HTML version of the DataTable
$html = "<table><tr><td>bug_id</td><td>bug_status</td><td>resolution</td><td>short_desc</td><td>deadline</td></tr>"
foreach ($row in $table.Rows)
{ 
    $html += "<tr><td>" + $row[0] + "</td><td>" + $row[1] + "</td></tr>" + "</td></tr>" + $row[2] + "</td></tr>"
}
$html += "</table>"

# Send the email
$smtpserver = "<SMTPSERVER>"
$from = "test@test.com"
$to = "test2@test.com"
$subject = "Hello"
$body = "Hi there,<br />Here is a table:<br /><br />" + $html
Send-MailMessage -smtpserver $smtpserver -from $from -to $to -subject $subject -body $body -bodyashtml
```

Comment: Hi, I got the issue resolved by other means. Thanks for your help and providing the solution too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have other problems, but the date arithmetic is definitely one issue.

MySQL has very strange rules about date arithmetic.  The value of `CURDATE()` is not a date.  It is either a string or a number.  In a numeric context (`CURDATE() + 9` is a numeric context), then it returns a number.

So, the date 2015-01-25 is returned as the integer 20150125.  You can see this phenomenon on SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/52659).  This value plus nine is 20150134.  Not a valid date and not what you expect.

The easiest fix is to use `date_add()`:

```
SELECT  bug_id, bug_status, resolution, short_desc, deadline
FROM bugs
WHERE bug_status IN ('RESOLVED') AND
      deadline BETWEEN CURDATE() AND date_add(CURDATE(), interval 9 day)
```

Comment: I have resolved the incorrect query part, (editted the question with correct query)
Could you pls help with emailing results part?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to put this together from multiple sources that seems to work with any mySQL query you plug in accordingly. I figured I'd share in case anyone else finds it helpful. Seems to be reliable from what I tested at least. You don't need to build the HTML table in with the SQL logic this way.

```
## -- This will download the needed PS module and load it accordingly and then prompt you to save the mySQL credential to make the connection to the data source
## -- Run PowerShell as administrator
## https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/03/02/querying-mysql-databases.aspx

Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri https://github.com/adbertram/MySQL/archive/master.zip -OutFile  'C:\Users\user\desktop\MySQL.zip'
$modulesFolder =  'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'
Expand-Archive -Path  C:\Users\user\desktop\MySQL.zip -DestinationPath $modulesFolder
Rename-Item -Path  "$modulesFolder\MySql-master" -NewName MySQL

$dbCred =  Get-Credential
Connect-MySqlServer  -Credential $dbcred -ComputerName 'localhost' -Database sakila
## Enter the mySQL username and password when prompted

Invoke-MySqlQuery  -Query 'SELECT * FROM actor'
```

---

```
## --This will run automated after the PS module used to make the mySQL is already loaded and not prompt for credential to allow non-interactive runs
## --Embedded credential used here

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “password” -AsPlainText -Force
$dbCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“root”, $secpasswd)

Connect-MySqlServer  -Credential $dbcred -ComputerName 'localhost' -Database sakila
Invoke-MySqlQuery  -Query 'SELECT * FROM actor LIMIT 5'
```

---

```
## This runs the Function to do the alternating row colors in the HTML table
Function Set-AlternatingRows {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Line,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$CSSEvenClass,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$CSSOddClass
    )
    Begin {
        $ClassName = $CSSEvenClass
    }
    Process {
        If ($Line.Contains("<tr><td>"))
        {   $Line = $Line.Replace("<tr>","<tr class=""$ClassName"">")
            If ($ClassName -eq $CSSEvenClass)
            {   $ClassName = $CSSOddClass
            }
            Else
            {   $ClassName = $CSSEvenClass
            }
        }
        Return $Line
    }
}

## -- This portion builds the HTML table based on the SQL query which you can change accordingly for your needs
## https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1745-set-alternatingrows-function-modify-your-html-table-to-have-alternating-row-colors
## https://philerb.com/2011/11/sending-mail-with-powershell/
## https://thesurlyadmin.com/2013/01/21/how-to-create-html-reports/

$Title  = "My Report Title" 
$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
.odd  { background-color:#ffffff; }
.even { background-color:#dddddd; }
</style>
<title>
$Title
</title>
"@
$Pre = "<b>Table Title"
$Post = "<b>Table Footer"

$html = Invoke-MySqlQuery -Query 'SELECT * FROM actor LIMIT 5' | 
Select * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, HasErrors, Name, Table, ItemArray | 
ConvertTo-HTML -Head $Header -PreContent $Pre -PostContent $Post | 
Set-AlternatingRows -CSSEvenClass even -CSSOddClass odd

$emailSmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "587"
$emailSmtpUser = "Username"
$emailSmtpPass = "Password"

$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$emailMessage.From = "mailbox@gmail.com"
$emailMessage.To.Add( "mailbox@gmail.com" )
$emailMessage.Subject = "Test email from PowerShell"
$emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
$emailMessage.Body = @"
This is the body of the message.<br /><br /> $html 
"@

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer , $emailSmtpServerPort )
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass );

$SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
```

---

### Sources

- [Modify your HTML table to have alternating row colors](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1745-set-alternatingrows-function-modify-your-html-table-to-have-alternating-row-colors)
- [Sending mail with PowerShell](https://philerb.com/2011/11/sending-mail-with-powershell/)
- [How to Create HTML Reports](https://thesurlyadmin.com/2013/01/21/how-to-create-html-reports/)
- [Querying MySQL Databases with PowerShell](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/03/02/querying-mysql-databases.aspx)

Comment: I forgot to include the needed information to use the `Invoke-MySqlQuery` and the `Function Set-AlternatingRows` should be at the top of the bottom script unless you load it globally, etc. so I fixed that so someone has all the portions needed and in the correct order plus the comments, etc. in the scripts.Once it's all together and tested and confirmed then this works well--just change your variables accordingly where needed such as DB name, username, password, folder paths, SQL query, and so on.